# Where are the grassy plateaus caves in Subnautica?

Tags: subnautica

Can someone please tell me where the grassy plateaus caves are? I have looked everywhere on the internet for locations and there have been no answers, I've asked on reddit but no one's given an answer, answered it like it was a different question. Can someone please help me? I'm playing on Xbox One if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*The [Grassy Plateaus Caves](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Grassy_Plateaus_Caves) are a group of different cave systems found in the Grassy Plateaus biome.*"

→

> "*[Grassy Plateaus](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Grassy_Plateaus) cover vast areas where the seafloor is too deep for Creepvines to take hold. They feature a great diversity of life forms. They are generally one of the first biomes the player encounters in Subnautica.*"

See the magenta-coloured areas on the map below (spoiler alert!):

> [image: Map of Subnautica]

And [here](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Crater_Map#Caves) are the coordinates of several Grassy Plateau Caves entrances:

> *-700 -115 -100   Grassy Plateaus Caves entrance
>
>   -680 -130 -140  Grassy Plateaus Caves entrance
>
>   -645 -125 -150  Grassy Plateaus Caves entrance
>
>   -505 -100 -100  Grassy Plateaus Caves entrance*

You can check your current coordinates:

- On Xbox, either by pressing the <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>X</kbd> buttons simultaneously, or the <kbd>🗗</kbd> (access PDA) and <kbd>X</kbd> buttons simultaneously.
- On Xbox One, these buttons are <kbd>RB</kbd>+<kbd>LB</kbd>+<kbd>Start</kbd>.
- On PC, by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> (use <kbd>F8</kbd> to enable the mouse to navigate through the tabs).
- On PS4, it seems this option is unavailable.

Use this information to navigate to the correct locations in-game.

Using these coordinates, you can also 'warp' to those locations, using the [console command](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Console_Commands) `warp [x] [y] [z]`.
To use this, you'll need access to the console:

- On Xbox, while in-game and unpaused, bring up the console by holding <kbd>LB</kbd>+<kbd>RB</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> at the same time.
  You can access the Developer Tools by pressing <kbd>LB</kbd>+<kbd>RB</kbd> while paused.
  By pressing <kbd>☰</kbd>+<kbd>LB</kbd>+<kbd>RB</kbd>, you'll have improved console access.
- On PC, press <kbd>F3</kbd> to bring up a small menu where you can select the Disable Console option. Use <kbd>F8</kbd> to enable mouse selection, and make sure that option is disabled (enabling the console - you might need to check and uncheck the option for it to work). Now, within the game, you can bring up the console with the classic <kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>~</kbd> button.
- On PS4, use <kbd>L1</kbd>+<kbd>R1</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

(The gaming console buttons mentioned might have changed throughout the versions, and some features have been revoked, so if anyone could let me know the current keybindings of the gaming consoles in the comments, I'll update the post.
The PC keybindings are correct.)